# Conditional Where with matched results in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table Rdetails format as below

```
RId Rrating  RRatingId Rdetails
1    Low       1          3m
2    Medium    2          alco
3    Medium    2          hd
4    High      3          fascia
5    High      3          grainger
```

I need to get all rows in table with any High and Medium Rrating. But when there are medium Rrating records I need to check pass in RId to an Udf before I determine to include as part of result.

`Select * from Rdetails where RratingId in(2,3)`--I need to write conditional where here saying when Rid is 2 then where clause should have `where udfRdetails(Rid) = 'True'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `OR` logic, but beware using a function in your `where` clause is not a good for performance.

```
select *
from Rdetails
where RratingId in (2,3)
and (RId != 2 or udfRdetails(Rid) = 'True');
```